# Appending specific JS obj value into a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, bootstrap-modal

I have seven Course Titles that are displayed in their own divs and clicking on any of the divs opens a modal. The modal was hard coded into my HTML.

How can I append each Course Title into the modal that's clicked on? For instance, by clicking on the Animals div the modal pops up and the title "Animals" should be present as well. So far I've only been able to just show the first title `(Animals)` and show every title in every modal `(Animals,Capitals,Colors,etc)`.

#### JS snippet:

```
loadCategories(){

    let categs = _categories;

    // using templates to clone a single div based on how many Categories are present
    let $host = $("#host");
        for (var i = 0; i < categs.length; i++) {
           let $template = $("#template").clone();
           $template.find(".cat-box > .cat-title").text(categs[i].Title);
           // $(".modal-title").append(categs[i].Title) // ------- shows everything (must be due to the loop)
           $host.append($template.html());
        }

// wondering if categs[i].Title could be worked with somehow

     $(".modal-title").append(categs.Title)

    let container = document.querySelector("div#template");
        container.innerHTML = $host;

    }
```

#### Modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-id" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass multiple variable to bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585444/pass-multiple-variable-to-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296180/javascript-variable-to-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple javascript to grab the title you need from an elements attributes, and then add them to the modal.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.openModal').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    const title = el.getAttribute('data-title')
    
    document.querySelector('.modal').textContent = title
  })
})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="openModal" data-title="This is the new title">Click me</a>

<br />
<br />

<div class="modal">Pretend this is a modal title</div>
```